# Why we can't do List<Parent> mylist = ArrayList<child>();

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

Why we can't do

```
List<Parent> mylist = ArrayList<child>();
```

Comment: Nitpick: The `Parent` / `Child` metaphor is weird when discussion inheritance, since inheritance describes an *is a* relation. (Would you say a `Child` *is a* `Parent`?)

Comment: Because a family tree or hierarchy is often used as an analogy for a Java type hierarchy.  Although semantically you have a point.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Suppose we could. Then this program would have to be fine:

```
ArrayList<Banana> bananas = new ArrayList<Banana>();
List<Fruit> fruit = bananas;
fruit.add(new Apple());

Banana banana = bananas.get(0);
```

That's clearly not type safe - you've ended up with an apple in the collection of bananas.

What you *can* do is:

```
List<? extends Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Banana>();
```

this is safe, because the compiler won't then let you try to *add* to the list of fruit. It knows that it's a list of *some kind* of fruit, so you could write:

```
Fruit firstFruit = fruit.get(0);
```

but it doesn't know what exact kind of fruit it's a list of, and make sure you can't do the wrong thing.

See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ102) another explanation.

Comment: I like this explanation a lot.

Comment: Jon, you just related my question about AlignmentAssigner to this; I implemented the extends notation, and it works. One question: when I passed the filled array to the utility method extending my interface, that List changed type to the generic. Is it possible to have a method extend an interface, work on data implementing that interface, and then pass it back as the *original* type? My only hiccup is that I had to cast the newly generic List as using my implementation class.

Comment: @rainydaymatt: Not without making the type itself generic, no. Otherwise how would you preserve the information about which type of list you had?

Comment: I completely disagree with this line of argumentation. It's one thing to store a Banana as a Fruit; it's another to store a List<Banana> as a List<Fruit>.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not sure what you're arguing against then. I've explained why you *can't* treat a `List<Banana>` as a `List<Fruit>`.

Comment: In literal response to the original question, yes, you are correct; however, what is actually intended (not stated but intended) is for Bananas to be stored in a List<Fruit>.

Comment: @Andrew: I see no indication of that in the question. The question explicitly asks why we can't assign a value of type `ArrayList<child>` to a variable of type `List<parent>`. My answer explains that, and was accepted - what makes you think you know the OP's mind better than they do themselves?

Comment: Because I give him the benefit of the doubt of wanting to do something sensible but not quite understanding how it works. The sensible thing that he would want to be doing in order to come to that question of his is to store Bananas in a Fruit List even though the List is of Fruits. What he would not know by your answer is that he can e.g. extract Bananas out of the List and place them into the Fruit List. Then his intent makes sense, even though his question does not.

Comment: @Andrew: I see no reason not to think that the OP meant exactly what they asked. Similar questions have been asked very many times. When a question is clearly expressed - and the answer accepted without further comment - I would avoid trying to second-guess the questioner. Just because *you* find the question as written obvious doesn't mean the questioner did. (And it's still not clear in what way you "completely disagree with this line or argumentation" either.)

Comment: You mistook me: I wasn't second-guessing the questioner. I was saying your line of argumentation isn't robust. Hence "I completely disagree with this line of argumentation." The questioner was doing what the questioner always does. You however answered his question with tunnel vision, and you still can't see that or at least won't admit it. The point of his asking is to learn, not to have a super literal answer; he needs to understand, not just have an accepted answer. Anyways we're wasting our time now.

Comment: @Andrew: "I wasn't second-guessing the questioner." Yes, you were. You were guessing what they were unclear about beyond what was in the question. Unless you know the OP personally, you're guessing there. "I was saying your line of argumentation isn't robust." *Which* line of reasoning? The line of reasoning in my answer *is* robust, and explains clearly why the OP's code won't and shouldn't compile, which is what they asked. One thing we can agree on: this argument is a waste of time. I'm pretty confident in my ability to understand what questioners are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Because they're not the same type. Suppose you had another child class of `Parent` (`Child2` for the sake of argument), it would then be possible to put an instance of `Child2` into a `List<Parent>`, but type-incorrect to put it into an instance of `List<Child>`. Covariant inheritance is a real headache, and is only supported at all in Java for array types (where it can cause odd problems).

Answer (score -3):

It should be this way, because we can do:
Parent A = new Child();

Edit :   Wait, actually it works :

`List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<Parent>();
     List<ChildA> tmp = new ArrayList<ChildA>();
     list.addAll(tmp);
     List<ChildB> tmp2 = new ArrayList<ChildB>();
     list.addAll(tmp2);`

It's just that the direct cast is not supported.