# Java: Can't to generic List<? extends Parent> mylist

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, collections

The other Example is pretty complex and I didn't understand it at all, my problem is similar somehow but as I said it's simpler and might yield in simpler answer

```
public List<? extends Parent> myfunction(List<? extends Parent> mylist){
       mylist.add(new Child())  ; //Doesn't Compile
}
```

Comment: Show us how you declare the child and Parent classes. Plus I would suggest to always use First capital letter for any class name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a method that takes a list, adds something to it, and then returns the list. The list is generic and you want the return type to match the type of the parameter.

Here's how you do it, in the general case:

```
public <T extends Parent> List<T> myfunction(List<T> myList) {
   ... // Add something to myList
   return myList;
}
```

Specifically, you're trying to add `new Child()` to `myList`. This cannot work. `myfunction()` may be called with many kinds of lists, whereas adding `new Child()` can only work if the list is either a `List<Parent>` or a `List<Child>`. Here's an example for a List of different kind:

```
public static class Parent {}  
public static class Child extends Parent {}  
public static class OtherChild extends Parent {}

public <T extends Parent> List<T> myfunction(List<T> myList) {
  myList.add(new Child());
  return myList;
} 

myfunction(new ArrayList<OtherChild>());
```

In the last line, `myfunction()` is called with a List of `OtherChild` objects. Obviously, adding a `Child` object into such a list is illegal. The compiler prevents that by rejecting the definition of `myfunction()`

**Appendix**

If you want `myfunction()` to be able to add an element to `myList` you need to use a factory (since Java does not allow `new T()` where T is a type parameter - due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). Here's how `myfunction()` should look like:

```
public interface Factory<T> {
  public T create();
}

public <T extends Parent> List<T> myfunction(List<T> myList, 
                                             Factory<? extends T> factory) {
  myList.add(factory.create());
  return myList;
}
```

And now, its usage:

```
public static class ChildOfOtherChild extends OtherChild {}

myfunction(new ArrayList<OtherChild>(), new Factory<ChildOfOtherChild>() {
    @Override public ChildOfOtherChild create() { return new ChildOfOtherChild(); }
  });
}
```

Comment: That much better, but how to create an element of type T?

Comment: This cannot work in Java. You cannot do `new T()` where T is a type parameter. You can use a factory to overcome that (I am writing an appendix to the answer which discusses this)

Answer (score 5):

What `List<? extends Parent>` means is "a list that contains only instances of some unknown subclass of `Parent`" - and since you don't know what subclass it is, you can't add anything except `null` to the list (you can get `Parent` instances from it, though).

If you have a specific subclass `Child` that you want to add instances of to the list, then what you really need is this:

```
public List<Child> myfunction(List<Child> mylist)
```

Comment: "can't add anything" isn't exactly true. You *can* add `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Following on Jon Skeet's example in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild), let's say you used

```
public List<? extends Fruit> myfunction(List<? extends Fruit> mylist){
       mylist.add(new Apple())  ; //Doesn't Compile
       return myList;
}
```

but then called it with

```
List<Banana> bananas = new ArrayList<Banana>();
bananas = myfunction(bananas);
```

You can't add an apple to a list of bananas.

What you **can** do is

```
public List<Fruit> addApple(List<Fruit> mylist){
       mylist.add(new Apple())  ; 
       return myList;
}

public List<Fruit> addBanana(List<Fruit> mylist){
       mylist.add(new Banana())  ; 
       return myList;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What about adding a `return` statement, or declare the method to return `void`...

Comment: the example was written for explanation  purpose only as you can see I used the parent and child analogy feel free to edit

Comment: Yea this is also the issue here.

Comment: What are you saying here?

Comment: I was pointing (6 years ago) the most obvious reason why the piece of code is not compiling (the function has a return type but no return statement).