# Java: Polymorphism and invoking methods

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why we can't do List<Parent> mylist = ArrayList<child>();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild)

I've a question on polymorphism and invoking methods.

My service layer signature is `public void saveRules(String paramOne, String paramTwo, List<RuleDTO> rules)`

My `EvaluationRuleDTO extends from RuleDTO`

So from my controller I attempt to perform the following:

`service.saveRules(String paramOne, String paramTwo, List<EvaluationRuleDTO> rules)`.

But this is not allowed as it complains about `List<EvaluationRuleDTO`> rules not being `List<RuleDTO> rules`.

This does not make much sense to me. Is this a weakness in the Java language, or what concept am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: If you read that link, it becomes clear that this is not a weakness in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is happening because the polymorphism is applied in the List type, not in its generics.

**Edit 1:** Michael posted a comment with a usefull link.

**Edit 2:** You can do (from [Why we can't do List<Parent> mylist = ArrayList<child>();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild)):

```
List<? extends RuleDTO> list = yourEvaluationRuleDTOList;
```

Comment: OK, I get it now, makes sense. So what would be a good solution here to my problem? I think something using generics but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @DJoyce: I complemented my post using the tip presented in the link.

Comment: Now I get this error: The method saveRules(String, String, List<RuleDTO>) is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, 
 List<capture#1-of ? extends RuleDTO>)

Comment: Define your method like this and then use your original `List<EvaluationRuleDTO>` parameter:

`public <T extends RuleDTO> void saveRules(String paramOne, String paramTwo, List<T> rules)`