# Instanciate a vector of a type with subtype

Tags: java, object, instance-variables

If we have these class :

```
abstract class Figure{
}

class Cercle extends Figure{    
}
```

And if I write :

```
Vector<Figure> v = new Vector<Cercle>();
```

I have error :

```
incompatible types: Vector<Cercle> cannot be converted to Vector<Figure>
```

If someone know how it doesn't work, I am interesting to know why. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild

Answer (score 0):

Answered many many times. **Generic types in Java are not covariant.**