# Change type of ArrayList<Parent> to ArrayList<Child> when parent is abstract

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, abstract

My problem is that I've got 2 class: parent and child.

Parent class is `abstract` and child extends from them.

Then I've got a method that return a parent `ArrayList` and I need cast it to  `ArrayList` of child.

What I should do?

Comment: Would you please add your code? that will be better for solving your issue

Comment: @miaguicam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild I hope this will solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You could do by the following way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    abstract class Parent {
        void callMe(){
            System.out.println("Parent"); 
        } 
    } 
    class Child extends Parent {
        void callMe(){
            System.out.println("Child");
        }
    }
    public class TestClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Parent> alist=new ArrayList<Parent>();
            List<? super Child> alist2=alist;
        }
    }
```

`List<Parent>`  is not same as `List<Child>`. Compilor does not allow to assign the reference of `List<Parent>` to `List<Child>` even though List contains only Child Object.

For Example:

```
List<Parent>  parentList=new ArryList<Parent>();
parentList.add(new Child());
parentList.add(new Child());
parentList.add(new Child());
//This is not allowed
List<Child>  childList=(List<Child>)parentList;//Compiler Error

//But,This is allowed
List<? super Child>  childList=parentList; //Okey
```

This is allowed becuase using reference of `List<? super Child>` gurantees that the `List<Parent>` will not be corrupted.

Comment: Its working for me.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Blackcompe

If you are using the generic version of the list implementation, you don't need to cast, e.g.

```
ArrayList<BestTutor> list = null; 
BestTutor c = list.get(0);
```

`Generics` is a type-safety method that tells Java nothing other than a BestTutor will go into this collection, so you can always bet that `List.get()` will return a BestTutor or whatever the bounded object is. BestTutor is called the bounded object. If you don't use generics the bounded object is Object., e.g.

```
ArrayList<Object> list;
```

Although, this bounding is implicit, so it's just:

```
ArrayList list;
```

Java will check to see if computeArea has been overridden. If it has it will use that version, else it will use the inherited version. e.g.

```
class Parent {
    void callMe(){
        System.out.println("Parent"); 
    } 
} 
class Child {
    void callMe(){
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
} 
Child c = new Child(); 
c.callMe(); //will display Child
```

It would call the Parent version, which would print Parent, but we overrode the method. That's basic overriding. Java also has polymorphism:

```
Parent p = new Child(); 
p.callMe(); //will display Child
```

A reference of type Parent can refer to an instance of Child.

If you call a method of Parent that's been overridden by Child Java knows to call the Child's instance method, not the Parent's.

A little advanced, but that will really become useful in more advanced design methods, like `"coding to interfaces"`.