# Using parent classes in Java generics parameters

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand how generics in Java fully works. I have similar situation which I simplified in code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Collection<B>> map1 = test();
    Map<String, List<B>> map2 = test();
    Map<String, ArrayList<B>> map3 = test();
} 

private static Map<String, ArrayList<B>> test() {
    return null;
}
```

when creating map1 or map2 I get an error which says incompatible type - it was expecting ArrayList, but got Collection/List instead.

How do I solve such problem?

Comment: You might want to see previous questions on the matter: [Why we can't do List<Parent> mylist = ArrayList<child>();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild). [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code which will compile successfully:

```
public static <B> void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, ? extends Collection<B>> map1 = test();
    Map<String, ? extends List<B>> map2 = test();
    Map<String, ArrayList<B>> map3 = test();
}

private static <B> Map<String, ArrayList<B>> test() {
    return null;
}
```

You need to add `? extends Collection<B>` and `? extends List<B>` because writing `? extends Collection` means that the `Object` which forms the `value` of the `Map` is a `sub type` of `Collection` class and thus the `test()` will be called as it also returns a `Map` whose `value` is `ArrayList` type, which is actually a `sub type` of `Collection`

Also note that you need to add `<B>` in the signatures of `main` and `test()`

Hope it helps!