# How to make java function take a list of objects of any class

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Java function which takes a `List` of `List`s holding objects of **any** class, and then calculates the size of the set consisting of all different combinations of inner list objects, where all objects come from different lists. The algorithm is simple:

```
int combos(List<List<Object>> inList) {
    int res = 1;
    for(List<Object> list : inList) {
        res *= list.size();
    }
    return res;
}
```

But I'm getting this error when trying to run the function with a `List<List<Integer>>` object as input parameter:

```
List<List<Integer>> input = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
input.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
input.get(0).add(1);
input.get(0).add(2);
combos(input);
```

The error:

```
The method combos(List<List<Object>>) in the type SpellChecker is not applicable for the arguments (List<List<Integer>>)
```

As far as I understand, `Object` is the parent class of `Integer`. So why doesn't this work? How can I make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between `Object` and `Integer` does not apply to `List<Object>` and `List<Integer>`, see e.g. [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763750/why-we-cant-do-listparent-mylist-arraylistchild?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details.

Use a type parameter:

```
<T> int combos(List<List<T>> inList) {
    int res = 1;
    for(List<T> list : inList) {
        res *= list.size();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a type parameter in `combos`:

```
<T> int combos(List<List<T>> inList) {
    int res = 1;
    for(List<T> list : inList) {
        res *= list.size();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about nested generics.  The answer in that question provides some good info.

On top of the two good answers you already got here is another option.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> input = new ArrayList<>();
    input.add(new ArrayList<>());
    input.get(0).add(1);
    input.get(0).add(2);
    combos(input);
}

static int combos(List<? extends List<?>> inList) {
    int res = 1;
    for (List<?> list : inList) {
        res *= list.size();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works, if you don't need to specialize the List Datatype as `List<Integer>`

```
List<List<Object>> input = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

input.add( new ArrayList<Object>() );

input.get( 0 ).add( new Integer(1) );
input.get( 0 ).add( new Integer(2) );


combos( input );
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Since he askey how he can make it work and this makes it work it does?!

Comment: OP wants to invoke `combos` with a `List<List<Integer>>`, not `List<List<Object>>`

Comment: I don't see the big difference. either he has to edit the function or the function call since he did not specify which of both is fixed, I got a solution. But the problem is allready solved so the discussion is irrelevant :-D (EDIT) okay he specified in his question that the method is not fixed :-/